# Seal wood floor without changing the look

Tags: wood, sealing

I’m looking to seal my new engineered wood floor to help protect it from spills, including cat pee. I know it won’t perfect but want to increase my chances.

I don’t want to change the colour or the shininess of the floor.

Should I be looking at oil, or matte wax or another product?

Thanks

Comment: Lots of engineered woods out there. More info please. Have you contacted the mfr?

Comment: Anything that will change the surface enough to create a better seal probably will affect the look, oil won’t stop cat pee, wax type products may seal but will probably change the look.